# Batch file closing without displaying the contents from a txt file

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which takes file path as user input & calls a console app with that input & finally displays the output messages of my console app(which is written to a txt file using streamWriter) using the same txt file.
Here is my Batch file: Test.bat

```
@echo off
set /p folderPath= Enter the folder path:
D:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe %folderPath%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (D:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Solution.txt) do echo %%a
```

Now if i open cmd.exe & say below:

```
D:>Test.bat
```

This is working perfectly & showing up the messages written by console app to the Solution txt file in cmd window

But if am double-clicking on the same .bat file, cmd window opens up & asks for folder path, when given executes the exe & is writing my exe messages to Solution.txt, but not displaying the same in cmd window & instead gets closed up on itself.

Am i doing smethng wrong??
~Deepthi

Answer (score 0):

add

```
Pause
```

add the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

The massage actually appears within your console, but since the app is closing immediately you won´t notice it as it´s to fast. Simply add Pause at the end of your program. This enables you to close the app on user-input (press any key)